# BERT Model Evaluation Measure in terms of Syntax Correctness and Semantic Coherence

Tags: nlp, bert, language-model

For example I have an original sentence. The word barking corresponds to the word that is missing.

```
Original Sentence : The dog is barking.
Incomplete Sentence : The dog is ___________.
```

For example, using the BERT model, it predicts the word crying instead of 
the word barking. How will I measure the accuracy of the BERT Model in terms of how syntactically correct and semantically coherent the predicted word is?

(For an instance, there are a lot of incomplete sentences, and the task is to evaluate BERT accuracy based on these incomplete sentences.)

In other words, how will I measure the distance in terms of semantics in terms of model between the two words `barking` and `crying`.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You just stumble over one big problem in the NLP field : finding the perfect metric..

---

Most traditional metrics (BLEU, ROUGE, ...) simply does not take into account the distance in terms of semantics between `barking` and `crying`.

So according to these metrics, `The dog is crying` is as similar as `The dog is salmon` to the reference, `the dog is barking`.
From a human viewpoint, this is not correct, the first sentence is closer to the reference, because for example the second sentence makes no sense.

---

People recently tried to provide better metrics in this sense. You might be interested in [BERT score](https://github.com/Tiiiger/bert_score).

The idea is simply to use a BERT model (that have been pretrained, therefore have some linguistic knowledge) to compute how similar 2 sentences are.